# How do i loop through the fields of a form in python?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to find out how "complete" a users profile is as a percentage.

I want to loop through the fields of a form to see which are still left blank and return a completion percentage.

My question is how do I reference each form value in the loop without having to write out the name of each field?

Is this possible?

```
    completeness = 0
    length = 20 
    for x in form:
        if form.fields.values[x] != '':
            completeness += 1

    percentage = (completeness / length) * 100
    print(completeness)
    print(percentage)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific what "form" is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reference each form value in a loop without having to write out the name of each field in Python, you can use the `items()` method on the `form.fields.values` dictionary to iterate over the key-value pairs in the dictionary.

Here is an example of how you could update your code to use the `items()` method to loop over the form:

```
completeness = 0
length = 20
for key, value in form.fields.values.items():
    if value != "":
        completeness += 1

percentage = (completeness / length) * 100
print(completeness)
print(percentage)
```

Note that in the code above, the `items()` method is used to loop over the `form.fields.values` dictionary, and the key and value for each iteration are assigned to the `key` and `value` variables, respectively. This allows you to reference the value for each field without having to explicitly specify the field name.